# Windows host tunnel through a middle linux server to another linux host with limited ports

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel, reverse-proxy

#### Addendum:

I've seen question "[Windows HTTP tunnel through 2 Linux hosts?](https://superuser.com/questions/135833/windows-http-tunnel-through-2-linux-hosts)" and trying to learn something about the answers. I learned. I will start giving my problem, and then talking a little about my tests with answers of that question.

I'm trying to connect my windows host to a linux host, using a middle linux (the only one with external IP).

#### What's my problem:

My `windows host` doesn't have the ports I want open (game and traffic ports).

I have a `linux host` that have the ports I want open.

So, the problem would be solved if I could make a `ssh tunnel` through my `windows host`to my `linux host`. The problem is that both of then only have an internal IP (one is on my company, another is on my university).

The salvation: I have acces to my company's `linux server`, that has an external IP (200.X.X.X).

So, I'd like to use this `linux server` as an intermediate though my `windows host` and my `linux host`.

```
The complicating:
```

My `linux server` only has the port 110 open. I can only connect through ssh to it using the 110 port.

In other words: I'm needing an example such that I can make:

`windows host's` firefox, proxified to use localhost:9999

redirects its access to `linux server`,

that redirects its access to my `linux host`.

One (but not the only one) idea is reverse tunneling my `linux host` to my `linux server`, and then direct tunneling my `windows host` to my `linux server`, making this `linux server` redirect my `windows host` access to my `linux host`.

But I do not know the commands to try that.

I tried, but **with no success**:

linux host: `ssh -R 20000:localhost:22 middle_user@200.X.X.X -p110`

windows host: `ssh -L 9999:localhost:20000 middle_user@200.X.X.X -p110`

How can I do that?

#### My environment, in another words:

---

`Windows host` (internal IP == 10.X.X.X ; all ports open)

*going through*

`Linux Server` (external IP == 200.X.X.X ; **can only connect using ssh to it on port 110, the port 110 is the only open**)

*redirecting windows host traffic to*

`Linux Host` (internal IP == 192.X.X.X ; ports open, can connect using ssh on port 22)

---

#### Another addendum:

This would work if, on my `linux server`,  I could (in a perfect world) access my `linux host` (what is impossible, given that I have an internal IP on my `linux host`)

windows host: `ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 -D 9999 -p 110 middle_user@200.X.X.X`

linux server: `ssh -D 9999 linux_host_user@linux_host_ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from answer [How to ssh to an unreachable remote machine by tunneling through a server that everyone can reach?](https://superuser.com/questions/170758/how-to-ssh-to-an-unreachable-remote-machine-by-tunneling-through-a-server-that-ev/170803#170803)

The "solution" that worked is:

- on `linux-user`, I did `ssh -R 1234:localhost:22 server_user@200.X.X.X -p110`
- on `windows-user`, I did `ssh -L 1235:localhost:1234 server_user@200.X.X.X -p110`

then,

- on `windows-user`, I did `ssh -D 9999 -p 1235 linux-user@localhost`

and then, on `windows-user`, I could configure firefox to use proxy socks localhost:9999, and could access a server running on my linux-user machine.

P.S.: For ssh on windows, I used cygwin to install openssh, to facilitate things.